# How to eliminate line breaks and spaces around text in xPath

Tags: xpath

There is a page like the following:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;5-8&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
   <p></br>5-8</br></p>
   <p>&nbsp;</br>5-8&nbsp</br></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

The goal is to abstract the text in each p, the breaks and whitespaces are not wanted.
How to achieve that?
Thanks in advance! Best Wishes!

--The first Updating
Another post suggested using normalize_space(). I tried that, well, It can remove the spaces. However,  only one node is left. How can I get all 30 node text without unwanted spaces? Thanks in advance and Best wishes!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEw9r.png)

Comment: presumably XPath 2.0 or later?

Comment: Well, I did it with xPath Helper 1.0.13.  Can higher edition of xPath Helper extract all 30 nodes text  from unwanted spaces.

Comment: I just updated my xPath Helper to version 2.0, using the following pattern:          normalize-space(//p[@class='iteminfo__line2__jobdesc__salary']/text())     . The result is the same as that of xPath Helper 1.0.13, only one salary node text is left.    How to get all 30  "clean" salary  node text?

Comment: This is the target webpage:       https://sou.zhaopin.com/?jl=763&kw=Java&p=1                           Can anyone offer any suggestions

Comment: In a single expression in XPath 2.0 and later you are able to use e.g. `//p[@class='iteminfo__line2__jobdesc__salary']/normalize-space(.)` but XPath 1.0 doesn't support that, there you need to iterate `//p[@class='iteminfo__line2__jobdesc__salary']` in a host language and output the result of each `normalize-space(.)` call.

Comment: I'm assuming the questioner is referring to Chrome's XPath Helper extension, which I _believe_ supports v1.0 of the XPath language (using the browser's own XPath engine)

Comment: NB the `normalize-space()` function won't discard "non-breaking" spaces. In XPath you'd need to use something like the `translate` function to remove them (by "translating" that character to the empty string)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to achieve what you want entirely in XPath 1.0, but in XPath 2.0 or later it is possible.

You don't say what XPath interpreter you have available but you mention Chrome's XPath Helper which relies on Chrome's built in XPath interpreter which supports XPath 1.0 (as is the norm for web browsers).

But it's possible you are just using Chrome to examine the data, and have another, more modern XPath interpreter such as e.g. Saxon. If so, an XPath 2.0 solution will work for you, though you won't be able to use it in Chrome, obviously.

I've tidied up your XML example:

```xml
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <p>  5-8  </p>
   <p><br/>5-8<br/></p>
   <p> <br/>5-8 <br/></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

NB those are non-breaking spaces there.

In XPath 2.0:

```xpath
for $paragraph in //p 
return normalize-space(
   translate($paragraph, codepoints-to-string(160), ' ')
)
```

NB this uses the `translate` function to convert non-breaking spaces (the char with Unicode codepoint 160) to a space, and then uses `normalize-space` to trim leading and trailing whitespace (I'm not sure what you would want to do if there were whitespace in the middle of the para, instead of just at the start or end; this will convert any such sequence of whitespace to a single space character). You might think `normalize-space` would be enough, but in fact a non-breaking-space doesn't fall into `normalize-space`'s category of "white space" so it would not be trimmed.

In XPath 1.0 is not exactly possible to do what you want. You could use an XPath expression that would return each `p` element to your host language, and then iterate over those `p` elements, executing a second XPath expression for each one, with that `p` as the context. Essentially this mean moving the `for ... in ... return` iterator from XPath into your host language. To select the paragraphs:

```xpath
//p
```

... and then for each one:

```xpath
normalize-space(
   translate(., ' ', ' ')
)
```

NB in that expression, the first string literal is a non-breaking-space character, and the second is a space. XPath 1.0 doesn't have the `codepoints-to-string` function or I'd have used that, for clarity.
The `.` which is the first parameter to the `translate` function represents the context node (the current node). When you execute this XPath expression in your host language you need to pass one of the `p` elements as the context node. You don't say what host language you're using, but in JavaScript, for instance, you could use the `document.evaluate` function to execute the first XPath, receiving an `iterator` of `p` elements. Then for each element, you'd call its `evaluate` method to execute the second XPath, and that would ensure that the `p` element was the context node for the XPath (i.e. the `.` in the expression).